# Floating point not iterable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, floating-point

I wanted to store floating point values in a list iteratively but it says floating point not iterable even if the iteration value was integer

```
n=int(input('Please enter value of N: '));
for i in range(n):
   x=list(float,input('Please enter the values of X'+str(i)+': '));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your input to float using `float(input(...))` and then append it to a list, also you do not need a semicolon `;` in python

```
n=int(input('Please enter value of N: '))
x  = []
for i in range(n):
   x.append(float(input('Please enter the values of X'+str(i)+': ')))
print(x)
```

The output will be.

```
Please enter value of N: 3
Please enter the values of X0: 1
Please enter the values of X1: 2
Please enter the values of X2: 3
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
n = int(input('Value for n: '))
lst = [float(input(f'Value for {x}: ')) for x in range(n)]
```